# React - cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element

Tags: reactjs

I have a [stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-tbn72b)

It's a super simple app that should just show an input with test below and the output of whats been put into the input field.

I'm getting an error on the input component

```
'CustomInput' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element.
```

Can anyone see why I'm getting this error

Comment: The code should be in the question, with off-site versions as support. However, the off-site code does not seem to replicate your question anyway.. Did you link the correct example?

Comment: Sorry I have updated it now with the correct link

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to add parenthesis after return:

```
const CustomInput = ({children, value, onChange}: CustomInputProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="search">{children}</label>
      <input id="search" type="text" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-pb6jpc?embed=1&file=index.tsx

---

If you are writing

```
const CustomInput = ({children, value, onChange}: CustomInputProps) => {
  return 
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="search">{children}</label>
      <input id="search" type="text" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
}
```

this is transformed as

```
const CustomInput = ({children, value, onChange}: CustomInputProps) => {
  return;
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="search">{children}</label>
      <input id="search" type="text" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
}
```

so you function basically returns `undefined` and is interpreted as

```
const CustomInput = ({children, value, onChange}: CustomInputProps) => {
  return undefined;
  // nothing after return counts
}
```

Comment: OR move <div> to the same line as return

Answer (score 4):

A better way of defining the types for props is :

```
const CustomInput:React.FC<CustomInputProps> = ({children, value, onChange}) => {
  return  (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="search">{children}</label>
      <input id="search" type="text" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  )
}
```